# What are your favourite free fonts?

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

As super users, using nicer fonts is often an important issue. Now that many sites are using @font-face to embed fonts in the page, having the same fonts installed locally means less downloading, and producing documents with custom fonts often look nicer. What are your favourite fonts?

Ideally fonts that have unicode support and that have proper ligatures and kerning.

Please add pictures if possible!

Comment: does Consolas count?

Comment: Most fonts that come with a commercial OS have been licensed for inclusion in the OS and are not available for free. I don't think these fonts should be included in a list of the best free fonts.

Comment: Do Minion Pro and Myriad Pro count (they come bundled for free with Acrobat Reader)?

Answer (score 8):

**[Gentium](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=Gentium)**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The free fonts from the Exljbris foundry.

Notably:

**[Anivers](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/anivers.html)**

[image]

**[Fontin Sans](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/fontinsans.html)**

[image]

**[Museo](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/museo.html)**

[image]

All of these can be downloaded from MyFonts, and they all have free options. Definitely worth while getting! These are the fonts I've seen most commonly embedded with @font-face.

Comment: That Fontin Sans is looking like a really nice font. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**[Linux Libertine and Biolinium](http://linuxlibertine.sourceforge.net/Libertine-EN.html)**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [DejaVu fonts](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page):

[image]

Standard on most Linux distros and freely downloadable for Windows, OS X, and other *nixes.

Answer (score 2):

Calibri:

[image]

Comment: The thing that annoys me with Calibri is it's small size in comparison with other fonts. It makes it almost unusable on the web :(

Comment: Calibri can hardly be described as "free", not as in beer and certainly not as in speech.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to [Bitstream Vera Sans Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera) (specifically as my programming font).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Helvetica comes 'free' with OS X and is delicious.

Comment: Though notably not Windows unfortunately. Helvetica Neue looks particularly delicious on screen.

Comment: tr/most operating systems/OSX/.  I cannot think of one other system that comes with this font 'free'.

Comment: URW++ created a free version of Helvetica that is distributed with Ghostscript, although I think for trademark reasons they call it something different.

Comment: There's a couple of lookalikes - Bitstream Vera Sans and DeJaVu Sans spring to mind as free alternatives. They don't have quite the same feel though.

Comment: Helvetica is nowhere close to a FREE font.

Answer (score 0):

The [Freefont](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) family.

[image]

They are free replacements for Helvetica, Times, Courier. Their Latin scripts are excellent; other scripts (e.g. Greek) need more work, especially in the kerning department, but they are a work in progress and everyone can (and does) help on occasion.